# Is there a Direct 3D equivalent of glxinfo?

Tags: direct3d

I need to make sure my machine can create a D3D window before even trying to open it.  How can I do so?

Comment: Which version of DirectX are you using?

Answer (score 4):

I've found the equivalent of `glxinfo` for directX -- it's called [dxdiag](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190900) and is provided by Microsoft. This lets you output an xml file with a `D3dStatus` field (which says "not available" in my case).

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to take a look at [DeviceCaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.directx.direct3d.devicecaps.aspx). It should be able to tell you the capabilities of the device so that you don't try to create a window that it doesn't support.

Answer (score 3):

Actually *glxinfo* does create a OpenGL window and creates a OpenGL context, but never maps it to the screen. One must create a OpenGL context to get all the information, like *glxinfo* does.

Comment: Great comment, but doesn't answer the question about D3D.

Comment: @MatthewRead: The OP asked about getting GPU information without context creation. He assumed glxinfo would gather its information without create a window. To which I replied, that glxinfo actually does the usual thing. I think it's not very hard to think about the logical step of doing the same with Direct3D; trying to create a Direct3D window/context to see what the machine can actually do.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Direct3D11 you can use this code

```
// Determines feature level without creating a device.
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL determineHighestSupportedFeatureLevel()
{
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL FeatureLevel;

    hr = D3D11CreateDevice(
        nullptr, 
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, 
        nullptr, 
        0, 
        nullptr, 
        0,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION, 
        nullptr, 
        &FeatureLevel, 
        nullptr );

    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        throw std::runtime_exception("Determine the highest supported Direct3D11 feature level failed.");
    }

    return FeatureLevel;
}
```